# Can I upload a .tex (not zip) file to Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to write a paper for a [conference](https://www.abstractscorecard.com/cfp/submit/login.asp?EventKey=VMPLDJWE), and I only use Overleaf.

The conference Latex template is given here
[conference template](https://www.conferenceabstracts.com/uploads/documents/12130/template_peerReviewed.tex)

However, when I copy the file and build in Overleaf. it give error.
The error is:

LaTex Error: File 'aesconf.cls' not found.
main.tex, line 3.

[image]

THe latex file MWE:

```
% Template for non-peer-reviewed articled
 \documentclass[convention,peer-reviewed]{aesconf}


% Graphics path
\graphicspath{{./}{figures/}}

% UTF-8 encoding is recommended but use one that works for you.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Highly recommended package for better looking text automatically.
\usepackage{microtype}

% Natbib is used for more control on citations. You can use other modern
% bibliography packages but please try to match the provided style.
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}


% These are useful for different purposes.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}


% The full title of the paper
\title{Very long title of complex audio algorithms and results}

% Put the authors in order here. The number in brackets define the corresponding affiliation.
\author[1]{John Smith}
\author[1,2]{Teri Jones}
\author[2]{John Maclane}

% Affiliations go here
\affil[1]{First University}
\affil[2]{Second company}



% Correspondece should include the corresponding author's name and e-mail address
\correspondence{John Smith}{john.smith@fakemail.com}

% These are used for headers. Anything that fits is okay. Please use proper punctuation.

% If there are many authors, please use the form "First author et al."
\lastnames{Smith, Jones, and Maclane}

% Short title should describe your topic but not be too long.
\shorttitle{Audio algorithms and results}


% This is required and draws the top title
\include{aestitle}

\begin{document}


\twocolumn[
\maketitle % MANDATORY!

\begin{onecolabstract}
Write the abstract here.
\end{onecolabstract}
]

\section{Introduction}

Introduce to the topic.

\section{Methods}

Show your methods.

\section{Results}

Present results.

\section{Discussion}

Discuss the results.

\section{Examples}

Here are a few examples on LaTeX.

\subsection{Citations}

Citations can be used as follows, \citet{Pulkki1997:VBAPbase} created VBAP and DirAC \citep{Pulkki2007:DirAC_JAES}. Notice the difference in the reference types allowed by natbib-package.

\subsection{Equations}

Equations are used often in text and Equation \ref{eq:firsteq} shows an example of this.
\begin{equation}
\cos(2\alpha)=e^{j2\pi}-2\sin^2(\alpha)
\label{eq:firsteq}
\end{equation}

\subsection{Tables \& figures}

Tables can be created in various ways and for various purposes. The example in Table \ref{tb:firsttb} shows basic trigonometric values using booktabs formatting.

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{This table shows a few trigonometric values.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
$\theta$ & $\sin(\theta)$ & $\cos(\theta)$ \\
\midrule
$\pi/4$ & $\sqrt{2}/2$ & $\sqrt{2}/2$ \\
$\pi/3$ & $\sqrt{3}/2$ & $1/2$ \\
$\pi/2$ & $1$ & $0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tb:firsttb}
\end{center}
\end{table}

There are also various ways to include and even draw figures in LaTeX. The most common is to include them. As is shown with Figures \ref{fg:sincplot} and \ref{fg:AESspec_jet}. LaTeX places the figures in the optimal place in the document by its typesetting rules but appropriate location can be hinted with [t], [b], and [h] arguments (corresponding to top, bottom, and here). Combination of these are also allowed. AES instructions recommend only placing figures and tables at the top or the bottom of the document but getting the preferred result might require some tuning by hand.

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{results.pdf}
\caption{This is an example of using the pdf format showing means and confidence intervals of audiometric data.}
\label{fg:sincplot}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{spectrogram.png}
\caption{This is a spectrogram of a spectral delay filtered sawtooth waveform using the png format.}
\label{fg:AESspec_jet}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\section{Summary}

Summarize your work and conclude.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum, libero nec scelerisque condimentum, libero mi porta dui, sit amet varius enim dui nec nisi. Suspendisse nulla nibh, lacinia in sapien at, tempus faucibus dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut facilisis erat accumsan tempor faucibus. Suspendisse ac dolor id odio iaculis sodales. Mauris nec arcu non tellus luctus mollis at vitae mi. Curabitur posuere feugiat molestie. Curabitur ac lorem vel arcu gravida volutpat.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In lacus est, accumsan non dictum nec, volutpat non justo. Sed auctor scelerisque ante, vitae volutpat mauris elementum sit amet. Etiam interdum felis id dignissim imperdiet. Proin ullamcorper sit amet augue quis consequat. Nulla varius enim sed nisl tempus, a ultricies sem finibus. Ut vel purus malesuada, sagittis ligula ut, luctus velit. Suspendisse iaculis magna id est consectetur condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce erat justo, auctor ut malesuada sed, ultrices eu odio. Integer vitae facilisis eros, sed dapibus lacus. Sed eleifend, risus ut congue tincidunt, nulla ipsum vestibulum diam, ut laoreet metus erat auctor nunc. Donec nisi diam, aliquam eget pharetra non, viverra non enim.

Integer facilisis elit id mauris laoreet gravida. Etiam dictum auctor nibh, ac pharetra est aliquam et. Praesent a ligula ut turpis egestas cursus vel non ante. Nam varius facilisis urna eget finibus. Duis eleifend dui id lacus tempus aliquet. Praesent vel sodales dolor. Suspendisse potenti.

Curabitur nisi felis, mollis non justo nec, sollicitudin ullamcorper lorem. Nunc mattis ullamcorper vestibulum. Aenean vitae turpis vel ipsum porttitor placerat. Etiam quis turpis quis nulla cursus rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed auctor est sed vehicula dignissim. Sed vel sem eget odio sagittis pharetra ut eu ex. Nullam fermentum ipsum non lacinia sollicitudin. Vestibulum purus ex, volutpat rutrum velit vitae, pulvinar ullamcorper mi. Maecenas tristique turpis ut justo pellentesque, in hendrerit ligula commodo. Pellentesque eget dignissim tellus.


\bibliographystyle{jaes}

% Reference to bibliography file.
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add `aesconf.cls` to your overleaf project too.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your reply. However, where I can get `aesconf.cls` file? I suppose is from conference, but is not there in website

Comment: Then you have to contact them. Googling it finds this, but I have no idea if that is official or not. https://github.com/SteakConferencing/publications/tree/master/2016-09-29-aes_141th

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you, is the conference need provided a complete set. thanks for your explanation